# Calculate Time Passed After Item Created Using Javascript (or other)

Tags: list, calculated-column, date-time

I have a list that tracks loaned equipment.  I want a little icon that is a visual indication at how long the item has been on loan to help visually cue employees to follow-up.

For example:

> 0-4 hours: green icon
>   4-8 hours: yellow icon
>   8+ hours: red icon

My first thought was using a "IF `NOW` + 4hrs >= `CREATED` Then ..." function in a calculated field.  I've been on a Google manhunt looking for a simple way to implement a `TODAY` call in a calculated field; I've learned, however, that since a calculated field is only generated once (it is static) when the item is saved, it's not going to help me.

Not sure where to turn now.  I thought maybe I could find something that uses JavaScript to do the `NOW` logic based on the `CREATED` field ... but I can't find anything specific to my needs and I don't know even JavaScript to write my own.

Anyone have other ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

PS: I don't have access to SharePoint Designer.  Am just a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SharePoint Designer is out, you could use jQuery and [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) to create your own display.  Using SPServices, you can use the GetListItems operation to pull back the items in the list.  Then based on the created date you'd be able to build your own HTML output utilizing some of the internal SharePoint icons to give a status dashboard.

If you don't want to do it from scratch, then look at [this article](http://sharepointjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/compare-duedate-with-today-in-list-view/) from Alexander Bautz.

Comment: I got the jQuery example from Alex to work - nicely done.  Thanks!